# Is throughput on higher bandwidth networks hindered by smaller UDP packet size?

Tags: networking, udp, throughput

I recently conducted an experiment on UDP throughput across 802.11g networks, using packet sizes between 100 and 1000 and bandwidths ranging from 6Mbps and 54Mbps.

I have noticed that that higher bandwidths are not performing as well as i had anticipated, and i have a feeling that this may be due to my packet sizes used. Would my throughput on the higher bandwidth networks have been higher if i had opted for larger packet size? and if so why?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a wireless network sending longer packets naturally takes longer time and hence the probability of radio interference is higher which causes more retransmissions reducing the effective bandwidth. The optimal packet size in a wireless network is probably dependent on the amount of noise in the area.

Comment: This is very insightful, indeed wireless networks are different in this regard.

Comment: Perhaps i should have mentioned that the experiment was conducted within an anechoic chamber so the noise was as minimal as possible.

Comment: Interesting. You may like to check the wireless NIC error counters to see if there are any retransmissions. `ifconfig` may not display these.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming IPv4, there is a 28 byte overhead on UDP packets, i.e. the real IP packet size is UDP payload size + 28. So for example if you are sending 56 byte packets the overhead is 100%. If you are sending 280 byte packets it is 10%. So the throughput goes up.

Comment: That's true for wired networks, but not so for wireless ones. 802.11g in question is wireless.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin So which part of it isn't true in a wireless network?

Comment: _the throughput goes up_ part.